# Amazon EC2 instance-reboot on EBS backed instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs, amazon-ami

I received notification that many of my EC2 instances will be rebooted for scheduled maintenance.  They are scheduled for an "instance-reboot," which makes sense because most of my instances are S3 backed.  However, I have EBS instances that are schedule for an "instance-reboot" as well.  It was my understanding that EBS instances are self contained because they are on EBS backed storage.  That said, why do my EBS instances require a "instance-reboot"?

Comment: Looks like you're correct, I looked at the earlier e-mail and that was indeed a `system-reboot`. The e-mail I got this time for the `instance-reboot` stated "One or more of your Amazon EC2 instances have been scheduled for a reboot in order to receive some patch updates." which sounds like it's for the EC2/VM tools on particular instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon is upgrading EC2, and as such many EC2 instances must be rebooted, hence the "instance-reboot" status. You can reboot these instances yourself on your own schedule, or wait for the scheduled task to run. The reboot has nothing to do with the storage engine, but more about the kernels that are backing the virtual machines.